# как правильно описать заголовок функции для собственной библиотеки

Tags: ассемблер

```
.386
.model flat, c
option casemap: none


.CODE


DllMain proc stdcall hlnstDLL:DWORD, reason:DWORD, unused:DWORD
  mov EAX, 1 
  ret
DllMain Endp



 swap proc 
    PUSH EAX
    PUSH EBX
    PUSH EDI
    PUSH ESI
    MOV EDI,  [ESP+20]
    MOV EBX, dword ptr[EDI]
    MOV ESI,  [ESP+24]
    MOV EAX, dword ptr[ESI]
    MOV dword ptr[EDI], EAX
    MOV dword ptr[ESI], EBX
    POP ESI
    POP EDI
    POP EBX
    POP EAX
ret
swap endp

End DllMain
```

.def файл

```
LIBRARY a
EXPORTS
_swap = _swap@0
```

Как правильно описать заголовок в стиле `cdecl` в .def файле, чтобы скомпилировать, а после корректно использовать в коде на с++?